# Why is cancelling an order not working?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

When payment fails the following code is called:

```
if ($order->getId() && Order::STATE_CANCELED !== $order->getState()) {
            $order->cancel();
            $order->addStatusHistoryComment($message);
        }
```

When I open that order in the back the status is not set and it contains no message in the Comment History

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to save order in last.

```
if ($order->getId() && Order::STATE_CANCELED !== $order->getState()) {
        $order->cancel();
        $order->addStatusHistoryComment($message);
        $order->save();
    }
```

Comment: It is saying that the `save()` method is deprecated

Comment: save() needs to be used, you can refer here,
Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_OrderController

Comment: @seenii, the `save` method should not be used. You should use `\Magento\Sales\Model\OrderRepository::save()` instead. If you want to cancel an order you can use `\Magento\Sales\Model\Service\OrderService::cancel()`

Comment: @jonijones Please supply an answer and I will mark it

Comment: @StevieG posted more detailed answer

Answer (score 2):

The model methods like `save` should not be used, these methods are "private" Magento code and marked as deprecated.

Magento has API interfaces, which allow working with entities as you need.

You should use `\Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface::save` to save the entity.

In your case to change order status to cancel the `\Magento\Sales\Api\OrderManagementInterface::cancel` and `\Magento\Sales\Api\OrderManagementInterface::addComment` should be used instead.

Also, if develop a 3rd-party application, you can use Magento WEB API to work with orders:

1. `/V1/orders/:id/cancel` - cancel an order.
2. `/V1/orders/:id/comments` - adds comment to existing order entity.
3. `/V1/orders/` or `/V1/orders/create` - creates/updates order.

More details in [Magento REST API](http://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/index.html#/) documentation.